# How to reduce the decimals in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I dont know much about python and am learning.

I have a variable like this,

```
a = 23.34853234
```

I want to reduce the numbers after dot. Like, i have mentioned below

```
a = 23.35
```

Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/python-limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)?

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20089808/790387).

Comment: There are some options, see [this post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389846/python-decimals-format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `round`

```
round(a, 2)
```

you can read more about it here [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)

Comment: can we use `floor` instead of `round`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
a = float("{0:.2f}".format(a))
```